# Creating a weekly Trigger which execute on particular days of week (Quartz Scheduler API)

Tags: java, quartz

I am trying to build a Trigger in Quartz Scheduler API 2.3.0 version which should get executed with the following criteria.

1.Start on particular date (Jan 25, 2021)
2.Start at predefined time (08.00.00 AM)
3.Once in every 2 weeks
4.On these particular days of week (Monday,Tuesday,Friday etc)

but I am confused how I should add the condition to execute this trigger on particular days of week

Comment: Why should you want to schedule a task on a date which was set 9 years in the past? Do you want to build a time machine?

Comment: Sorry it was just an example...i have updated the question

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html, have you tried with above tutorial?

Comment: hi & welcome! problem: "Twice in a week" and "On these particular days of week" (3 + etc.?) possible: "twice a week" and (e.g.) "`MON,WED`"

Comment: sorry it is once in every 2 week

Comment: How do you combine `once in every 2 weeks` with `on days of week Monday, Tuesday, Friday`? Do you want to schedule it on every Monday, Tuesday and Friday every two weeks?

Comment: yes i want to schedule it once in every 2 week for mon, tue, fri starting at the given date and time

Comment: can anyone respond as soon as possible ?

Comment: @huy Detailed information is not available in link on how to configure weekly scheduler with above mentioned conditions

Answer (score 0):

You could use this cron scheduling `0 8 * * 1,2,5`.

It triggers at minute `0` at hour `8`, at every day of the month and at every month, but only at the weekday `1,2 and 5` which are Monday, Tuesday and Friday respectively.

And for the biweekly scheduling i would count the weeks since 2021-01-25 and check if `weeks % 2 == 0` and return from the task prematurely. Analogues for the starting date.